# How to create context menus that modify the Current Control?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

In my application, a `RichTextBox` is dynamically created when a certain form is opened.  Currently, clicking on the box opens up an `OpenFileDialog`, where the user selects a file, and then the file location is put into the `RichTextBox`.

My end user told me yesterday that he instead wants the following:

- Left-clicking the `RichTextBox` should open the specified file in explorer
- Right-clicking should open up a `ContextMenuStrip`, with one of the options in the strip being "Select File".

My revised code is contained in the following Gists:

My [openFileDialog](https://gist.github.com/JPeroutek/da8c45f10e9bd52411aa) sub, which handle the `.Click` event for the `ToolStripMenuItem`

```
Sub openFileDialog(ByVal sender As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim myOpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog()

    If Not sender.GetCurrentParent().Parent.Text = "" Then
        myOpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = sender.GetCurrentParent().Parent.Text
    Else
        myOpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    End If

    myOpenFileDialog.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*"
    myOpenFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1
    myOpenFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = True

    If myOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        sender.GetCurrentParent().Parent.Text = myOpenFileDialog.FileName
    End If
End Sub
```

My [fileControlRightClicked](https://gist.github.com/JPeroutek/e179a3414eac3bd3294e) sub, which handle the right-clicking of the `RichTextBox`

```
Sub fileControlRightClicked(ByVal sender As System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Button <> Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then Return

    Dim cms = New ContextMenuStrip
        'cms.Parent = sender
        Dim item1 = cms.Items.Add("Select File")
        item1.Tag = 1
        AddHandler item1.Click, AddressOf openFileDialog
        cms.Show(sender, e.Location)
End Sub
```

Other than those two pieces of code, then only relevant code I can think of is

`AddHandler .MouseUp, AddressOf fileControlRightClicked`

Which is used when the `RichTextBox` is declared.

How do I reference the specific instance of `RichTextBox` that is clicked?

Clearly, using `sender.GetCurrentParent().Parent` does not work, and neither does `sender.GetCurrentParent.SourceControl`.  (These can be seen in the openFileDialog gist above)

If I left out any relevant information or code, or was unclear about the problem I am having, please comment, and I will correct/add any necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a little casting to get the `RichTextBox` in `openFileDialog`:

```
Sub openFileDialog(ByVal sender As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim menu = DirectCast(sender.GetCurrentParent(), ContextMenuStrip)
    Dim rtb = DirectCast(menu.SourceControl, RichTextBox)
    ...
End Sub
```